# Google Map static vs Dynamic business and buildings view

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I have a problem when i try to display a static map  that display all elements

for example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=18&size=640x640&markers=color:red|40.7191413,%20-73.9973273

In it i can't view any business and buildings.

[image: Static Map]

If i display same map with same zoom in google maps or in any other application that dsplay dynamic map
i can view them.

For example:

https://www.google.it/maps/place/40%C2%B043%2709.1%22N+73%C2%B059%2751.0%22W/@40.7191413,-73.9973273,18z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0

[image: Google Map]

I have read this faq:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#no_pois
and tryng to apply it  in this mode:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&zoom=18&size=640x640&markers=color:red|40.7191413,%20-73.9973273&style=feature:poi.business|element:all|visibility:on

but don't work
I's a limit of Static Map o what?

Comment: You need to check difference between both url first. First one is loading static image of given latitude and longitude. second 1 is redirecting you to google map.

Comment: ok.. but i don't understand because static map don't display buildings

Comment: Static map is not displaying actual map. it is only displaying static image which will be look like map

Comment: therefore is'nt possible display building an other business place in static map?

Comment: No. you can check documentation of maps.googleapi.com

Comment: if you want a static map with all business, why not just take a screen shot? the static map provided by the url does show some business but it is limited. And also, why not just embed into an iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Static Map API typically shows fewer points of interest compared to Google Maps or the Maps JavaScript API. This is working as intended, so unfortunately you can't do anything to get more POIs to show up.

You can consider using the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/) which might better meet your needs.